# Maven Nested Modules - Naming Conventions/Best practices

Tags: java, maven, nested, naming-conventions, hierarchy

I just have I minor question where I did not find answers (or they were really old and I do not know if still accurate).

Lets assume I have something like a web application and I want to build it using maven.

Logically I might have something like the following structure:

```
application
    -client
        -theme
        -ui
    -server
        -service-1
        -service-2
```

Now how would the different groupIds and artifactIds look like?

And is it recommended/best practice that the root package name of a module is `groupId.artifactId`?
If yes, how do I handle a dash in my artifactId for the package name?

From my simple understanding I would have the following ids for the single modules (where application/client/server are just parent & aggregator poms):

```
my.domain:application
my.domain.application:client
my.domain.application.client:theme
my.domain.application.client:ui
my.domain.application:server
my.domain.application.server:service-1
my.domain.application.server:service-2
```

Or would it be better to prefix the non aggregating, non parent poms with the 
application name (basically the "Leafs" of the hierarchy)? Or simply every artifactId? Again: how to handle the package name then?

So that, e.g. in a WAR the libraries are better distinguishable?

```
my.domain:application
my.domain.application:client
my.domain.application.client:application-theme
my.domain.application.client:application-ui
my.domain.application:server
my.domain.application.server:application-service-1
my.domain.application.server:application-service-2
```

This somehow is really confusing for me..

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You might find the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25610544/421049 helpful.